# increase User control size while re-sizing Form

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application based on two user controls and one form. This form is parent to my 2 user controls and i pragmatically add them to the form. My issue here is that when anchor components in the user control, they are not anchored in the form. So when re-sizing the form by dragging one of the corners, it seems like the user control does not also get re-sized. I was told that i had to listen to the Forms size and append that size to the User control. Is that a good solution? if yes how would i do that?

My user controls are inserted in a tab component btw.

This is my code for adding the user controls to the form. (if it is needed)

```
public void addUC(UserControl control, TabPage tab)
{
    control.Parent = tab;
}
```

can anyone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to anchor the child usercontrols using the [`Anchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) property.

Answer (score 1):

If there are only 2 use controls in the form why not use dock - it will always stretch the use control to the maximum size of the form

Comment: So i have to dock the user controls to the Tab control and and then dock the tab control to the form ?

Comment: both controls sit inside the tab control? in the same tab or 2 different tabs?

Comment: ok,so set the tab control to dock - fill inside the form. and each use control will also have dock fill. that way tab control fills main form and each use control fills its own tab - they will always stretch with the form - no code from you needed to make this work :)